# question about accessing arraylist for another class

Tags: java

I have two class now and I want to make a T/F question quiz, I am stuck at how to use these two class,I have

```
public class TFQuestion {
    private String question;
    private boolean answer;
    private int skillLevel;

    public TFQuestion(String question, boolean isTrue, int level) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = isTrue;
        this.skillLevel = level;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String text){
        this.question = text;
    }

    public String getQuestion(){
        return this.question;
    }

    public void setAnswer(boolean isTrue){
        this.answer = isTrue;
    }

    public boolean getAnswer(){
        return this.answer;
    }

    public void setSillLevel(int level){
        this.skillLevel = level;
    }

    public int getSkillLevel(){
        return this.skillLevel;
    }
}
```

```
public class TFQuestionList {
    private ArrayList<TFQuestion> allQuestions;

    public TFQuestionList(int level) {
        allQuestions = new ArrayList<TFQuestion>();
        TFQuestion quest;
        if (level == 0) {
            quest = new TFQuestion("question1", true, level);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
            quest = new TFQuestion("question2.", false, level);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
            quest = new TFQuestion("question3", true, level);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
            quest = new TFQuestion("question4", false, level);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
        } else if (level == 1) {
            quest = new TFQuestion("Question 11", true, level);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
            quest = new TFQuestion("Question 12", false, level);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
            quest = new TFQuestion("Question 13", true, level);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
            quest = new TFQuestion("Question 14", false, level);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
        } else if (level == 2) {
            quest = new TFQuestion("Question 21", true, 2);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
            quest = new TFQuestion("Question 22", false, 2);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
            quest = new TFQuestion("Question 23", true, 2);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
            quest = new TFQuestion("Question 24", false, 2);
            allQuestions.add(quest);
        }
    }
```

For int level I already got it from another activity, I just have a hard time to access both class, like how can I use TFQuestionList in TFQuestion, what method should I use?
I can't put them together to access information I need in TFQuestionList and use method in TFQustion.
thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, you wouldn't put the `TFQuestionList` where `TFQuestion` would access it. You have a fairly nice model here in that you've modeled a question, and a list of questions. You have it setup so that the constructor takes a level and adds the questions.

So, leaving aside certain aspects of modifiability and exposing internals, I think what you would want do to is add to the `TFQuestionList` a getter method to get the questions:

```
public List<TFQuestion> getQuestions() {
  return allQuestions;
}
```

So someplace you are/will want to instantiate the `TFQuestionList` with the level, and then you will want to have some sort of display loop that presents the questions (and collects the input from the user).  You haven't shown the code for how you are doing that loop part, but conceptually it is straight-forward.